# simple subnetting, regarding vpn

Tags: vpn, cisco, routing, ipsec, subnet

i am using 2 cisco rv180 to build up a ipsec tunnel.

thats working.

but i cant get any packets trough the tunnel.

first i was using:

local: 10.0.0.X 255.0.0.0
remote 10.0.1.x 255.0.0.0

but 0 packets went trough the tunnel.
no ping, nothing.

then i realized that that is one giant subnet and
that this should be the reason

so i changed to:
local 10.0.0.x 255.255.255.0
remote 10.0.1.x 255.255.255.0

now i see some 8 packets an hour went trough the tunnel,
but i cant get any kind of connection between the computers.

if you need any more information, just ask, i ll lurk the thread,
till i figured out a solution.

Comment: This can't work. You've configured /24 subnets now, and 10.0.0.x and 10.0.1.x are not in the same /24 subnet.

Comment: well, as far is i know, you cant link the same subnet via vpn, cause the router then dosent know what to put into the tunnel and what not.
it needs to decide on some basis and thats subnet a is on side a from the tunnel, subnet b is on side b of the tunnel.

but maybe i am wrong there?

Comment: tried to say it again, but more clearly :)


as far is i understood, you cant link the same subnet via vpn, cause the router then dosent know what packets to put into the tunnel and what route locally.
the router needs to decide on some basis what packet has to go into the tunnel and that basis is the subnet.
subnet a is on side a from the tunnel,
subnet b is on side b of the tunnel.

thats how i understood it...

but maybe i am wrong there?

Comment: """to build up a ipsec tunnel.

thats working.

but i cant get any packets trough the tunnel.""" => thats NOT working.

Comment: sorry, i meant, the tunnel/link is UP

Comment: right now there are going packets trough the tunnel, but i dont know which packets... i cant capture from the bdg interface on the router, just wan and eth, but arp request dont get an answer from the other side.

Comment: i am off for today, cu tomorrow